# for loop second time click on Dom element not working in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, testing, puppeteer, testcase

I have main category > sub category > item to select random item using puppeteer i am using for loop but second iteration of for loop it not working...

it gives error like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUFI0.png)

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.menuCategoryLength = await page.$$eval(".menu-categories .slick-slide", div => div.length);
        this.categoryNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.menuCategoryLength) + 1;
        await page.click(".menu-categories .slick-slide:nth-child(" + this.categoryNo + ")", {delay: 200});

        await page.waitForSelector(".menu-subcategories");
        this.menuSubCategoryLength = await page.$$eval(".menu-subcategories .slick-slide", div => div.length);
        this.subCategoryNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.menuSubCategoryLength) + 1;
        await page.click(".menu-subcategories .slick-slide:nth-child(" + this.subCategoryNo + ")", {delay: 200});

        this.menuItem = await page.$(".menu-items .menu-item-wrap", {visible: true});

        if (this.menuItem) {
            this.menuItemLength = await page.$$eval(".menu-items .menu-item-wrap", div => div.length);
            this.max = this.menuItemLength > 1 && this.menuItemLength < 4 ? this.menuItemLength : 3;
            this.itemNo = this.menuItemLength === 1 ? 1 : Math.floor(Math.random() * this.max) + 1;
            await page.click(".menu-item-wrap:nth-child(" + this.itemNo + ")", {delay: 200});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well probably there isn't an element there. Have you checked the code with a normal Chrome DevTools console?

Comment: All the element is present there.

Comment: Please add the HTML to the question also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 (Math.floor(Math.random() * 0) + 1) === 1 //true
```

maybe the var `this.menuCategoryLength` is 0 and your code try to get `someSelector:nth-child(1)`